# Why are (hexadecimal) hashed passwords/cookies/.. saved as strings in databases?

Tags: efficiency

I'm wondering why all databases seem to store hashed passwords and typical hexadecimal data as char(x)/varchar(x)

MySQL uses latin1_swedish_ci as default character encoding, where each character is made of 8 bits.

When storing hexadecimal data as strings, you're only using 4 bits of those 8 bits you can use, as there are only 16 usable characters.

So am I not seeing something here? Is there a character encoding specifically for this kind of stuff using 4 bits per character? Or are some companies actually making use of all the reserved space to store hexadecimal stuff at least, doesn't matter how?

Comment: Why would you store binary data as a string? Hexadecimal is a way to represent the data as a string that is less verbose, it would be unusual / silly to actually store that as a string when the database supports binary types.

Comment: Looking at all the "tutorials" on the internet I've seen, nobody really seems to care about it..

Comment: I would avoid those “tutorials” then.

Comment: Nobody cares about saving 30 bytes per user in exchange for additional complexity.

Comment: Even storing the hashes as strings of hexadecimal characters, the "wasted" storage is neglible. Most systems will have maybe a few thousands of users, so you are looking at less than 100Kb of overhead. Even with millions of users, it's only a few megabytes of overhead. If you're Facebook and you have *billions* of users, then you are looking at gigabytes, but you are also then putting up hundreds of *tera*bytes of *RAM* just for caching (and your user database is likely highly partitioned).

Comment: Database development (okay, not development, but production and administration) involves a surprising amount of manual data modification requests, plus troubleshooting. This is where the convenience of strings trumps software development concerns.

Comment: Funny people would say it is more complex to store binary data as binary data. The chances for error increase when you round-trip binary data to strings; it is always better to store binary data as binary data, if you have that option.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Firstly, hexadecimal is not really a storage format... it is a display format.  You can choose to store hexadecimal strings in a database, if you wish, but the more natural (and more common) technique is to store the actual numbers in a database using the database's native numeric integer format, and then format the retrieved numbers as hexadecimal for display purposes.

Hash functions return a set of bits.  Traditionally, these bits are provided as hexadecimal because it is easier to read than zeroes and ones.  In addition, many hashes contain a larger number of bits than native numeric types can support (MD5 is 128 bits, for example), and so hex is a more natural choice.  Given an arbitrary number of hex digits, it's simpler and easier to just store the hex that the hash function provides.

**Further Reading**
[Why do we use hex output for hash functions?](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/34995/1909)
[Why do most hashing functions produce hashes that have characters a-f 0-9?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/21238)

Comment: Wheh hex uses 4 bits per byte, base64 uses 6; if efficiency of storing / transferring long bit strings _as plain text_ is important, base64 or ASCII85 can be used to improve efficiency.

Comment: The hex is for humans but the binary data is for the database, if possible.